# how to remove backslash from a string using redshift?

Tags: amazon-redshift

How to remove backslash in redshift?

For example:
1\234

I want only:
1 234

I have tried regexp_replace function but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

**REPLACE(string1, old_chars, new_chars)**

**`select replace('1\\2345','\\',' ')`**

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_REPLACE.html